# How do I pay for a Dartford crossing that doesn't seem to have been detected?

Tags: london, payment, tolls

I crossed the Dartford crossing twice today - first Southbound over the bridge around 11am, and then back Northbound through the tunnel around 5pm. According to the rules[*] this counts as two crossings and I should pay 2 x £2.50.

I very rarely use this crossing so I do not have an account. When I go to the [payment page](https://www.gov.uk/pay-dartford-crossing-charge), choose "Pay without an account" and enter my registration number, it says I have **one** crossing to pay for and asks me if this is correct. If I click no, it gives me a selection to make: 0 crossings or 1 crossing. No option for 2 crossings.

I don't want to pay for one crossing now and then get a PCN for the second crossing in a few days' time. How can I pay for both crossings now? Or, is it possible that my registration plate was not properly detected on one of the crossings and therefore I won't get charged for it?

[*] Taken from the payment page:

> How your payment amount gets calculated
>
> Recent crossings include all northbound and southbound crossings made yesterday and today.
> It costs £2.50 per crossing for a car, van or minibus less than 8 seats.
> A crossing is a single journey over the bridge (Southbound) or through the tunnel (Northbound).
> A return trip is 2 crossings.
> Late payments will be used for future crossings - you may receive a PCN for any late payment.

Comment: The "Pay Dart Charge" page you cite lists several methods of contacting the operator of the bridge and tunnel. Have you called or emailed to ask what to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I would not worry about this.**

Pay for the one crossing. Take a screenshot of the payment page. If at any point you are contacted to pay for the second crossing, show them the screenshot that proves it wasn't asked for.

Calling the operator will probably result in them spending more than £2.50 trying to sort it out. They won't thank you for it.

Comment: While I fully agree with taking a picture as proof, I believe the operator could indeed be thankful if a malfunction in the detection/accounting system is reported. Even while this is just one case - who knows how much they could be missing out in revenue when this happens more than on just one occasion..